# software center stops working

Tags: installation, software-center, flash

currently I'm updating my Ubuntu 13 with software center but it stopped working. There are no error messages but is clear to me it is not progressing.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? Iǘe never had this problem before and don know if is secure to kill the process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem. Any *-installer package downloads it's contents during install due to licensing restrictions. For your case, you may want to use package **adobe-flashplugin** instead of **flashplugin-installer**.

Anyway, if you want to use installer version, you have to check your network settings, and be sure that command `wget <url>` works proper.